# How to query Mailchimp API with python mailchimp3 library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have got the following code working:

```
campaigns = client.campaigns.all(get_all=False, count=5)
```

..But I want to query just campaigns in a given month or later than a specific date:

```
campaigns = client.campaigns.all({'since_send_time' : '2019-08-14T15:30:00+00:00'})
```

...But this gives a complete listing of all the campaigns rather than specific ones later than the date.

The library is [here](https://github.com/VingtCinq/python-mailchimp) and the link to the Python file where the campaigns query is [here](https://github.com/VingtCinq/python-mailchimp/blob/master/mailchimp3/entities/campaigns.py).  How do I format the query correctly please?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found out how to do it.
This worked for me:

```
r = e.campaigns.all(get_all=False, since_create_time="2019-10-02T00:00:00+00:00")
```

Remember it expects `**queryparams`, which is the same as `*kwargs`; meaning Python then expects a variable quantity of arguments